# Setting the security policy file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, security

From what I understand from [searching around](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed2.html) on the internet, if I want to run a java program with a security policy, I would have to type in something like

`java -Djava.security.policy=java.policy MainClass`

Where `java.policy` is the file describing the security policy.
How do I do something like that in Eclipse? I've tried adding `-Djava.security.policy=java.policy` under the `Arguments` of run configurations, but it doesn't seem like it has taken any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add it to the VM arguments, not the Program Arguments.

Another mistake could be the path. Did you use a relative or absolute path for the file? If relative, you should consider, that the Run configurations have the project folder as root, not the source folder. So if your policy file is in a subfolder, you have to mention that.

Comment: I've added `-Djava.security.policy=java.policy` under VM arguments, however I am suspicious because it looks like it's possible to add options by clicking on `Variables..`, and there doesn't seem to be anything related to what I am looking for.

Comment: I've put the `java.policy` file at the root of my project. I think java can see it, because when I loop over `new File(".").list()`, `java.policy` is listed as one of the files.

Comment: Actually I've tried it on the command line, and it looks like it didn't work there either. I found out I needed the `-Djava.security.manager` option as well. Now it works fine on Eclipse too.